# How to find my Dead Space 2 key?

Tags: drm, dead-space-2

I'm temporarily uninstalling Dead Space 2, which I installed a looong time ago. The uninstaller said that I should de-authorize the game to be given one of my 5 activations back. The tool to do so requires my serial number, but I can't for the life of me find it anywhere.

Where might it be available? I did not buy the game through Steam, but it was a digital download of sorts.

Given that the game is already installed and authorized, can I extract the key from the installation somehow?

Comment: Do you remember where you got the digital download from? They might have it for you.

Comment: @AshleyNunn No :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remember where you downloaded it form, because i can guarantee that you will have your key somewhere around there. Other than this you don't have any solution to this issue. (Perhaps you got it from greenmangaming.com or humblebundle.com from what i remember from past bundles) You should also check your email, because if you bought it, you will have a receipt specifying the place where you bought it from.

You cannot extract the key from anywhere within the game or installation.

Comment: Nope, not on Humble Bundle. Really annoying that de-authorization is impossible without the serial. I suppose it's somewhat understandable that I can't extract the key from the install. Oh well, better buy from a place I can remember next time!